# parent class reference variable unable to access methods in child class

Tags: reference, overriding

```
class A{

    void a(){
        System.out.println("hello a");
    }
}

class B extends A{

    void b(){

        System.out.println("hello b");
    }
}


public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        A a= new B();
        a.b();

    }
}
```

This does not give compilation error but gives run time error but when i do the same with overriding , that is i define method `b()` in `class A` also , that time it executes method in `Class B` , but when the names of method are different at that time it can not execute method in `class B`.
Please explain?

Comment: "This does not give compilation error" - Impossible. That code must not compile. Make sure the code you compile against is the same as that used at runtime. And please read up on the basics of object oriented programming.

Comment: Do you have idea on inheritance ? Anywhere in any book is it written that parent class's reference can access the child class method? Lol.

Answer (score 0):

This will give compilation error actually, the reason being method binding is done at compile time on the basis of reference now since there is no method b() in class A , so the class have no idea of this method ,Hence why compilation error.

Second 
class B's method will be called because at runtime the jdk know the type of the object , so the object method will be called . Hence B's method will be called.

You can also remove compilation error by adding a blank method void b() in class A , so now Class A knows about method b() but at runtime B's b() will be called

```
class A{

    void a(){
        System.out.println("hello a");
    }

    void b(){

    }
}

class B extends A{

    void b(){

        System.out.println("hello b");
    }
}


public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        A a= new B();
        a.b();

    }
}
```

To get no compilation error and only runtime error try this

```
A b=new A();
((B)b).b();
```